# How can I set an EC2 network interface to stop auto-assigning a public IP address?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I launched the majority of my EC2 instances with network interfaces that automatically assign public IP addresses. Now that I no longer want them to have public addresses, is there any way to disable this setting without having to create new interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

If you launch your EC2 inside a VPC, you can disable auto-assigning public IP address to subnet.

If you launch classic EC2, you can't do it.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#differences

Comment: The problem is that when launching a machine, you can override the subnet setting. The question is, how can this override be removed?

Comment: The documentation mentions that the ENI remembers the subnet setting from when it was create - editing it afterwards won't modify the interface setting. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#eni-basics